# How to print node registration form

Tags: forms, nodes

I'm trying to print Node Registration form so I used this code in node.tpl.php:

```
<?php
$form = drupal_get_form('node-registration-form');
print drupal_render($form);
?>
```

I've also tried id **node_registration_form** but it didn't work. Any ideas why?

**EDIT 1:**
Ok, so i used this in template.php:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars){
  $myspecialform = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('node_registration_form'));
  $vars['node_registration_form'] = $myspecialform;
}
```

and `print $myspecialform;` in node.tpl.php and it works but i got this error now:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function capacity() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\sites\all\modules\node_registration\includes\node_registration.forms.inc
>   on line 676

Should i alter the form in template.php and add capacity input?

EDIT 2:

Nevermind guys, this module provides a node registration form block. I'm blind :) But thanks for help!

Comment: Never ever use drupal_get_form in TPL!

Comment: Can you explain me why? Thanks

Comment: First, I was told so by the guy who *wrote* this function. Second - because templating stage is far to late to create content that has to be processed.

Comment: please edit your question with changes. It's OK as nobody answered yet.

Comment: If the form is the only thing on the page you should be using hook_menu (and it's a config page or something not content). Otherwise use blocks or panels or something. This should not need to be rendered in a tpl or preprocess to display.